# Add string one by one to textbox after pressing asp.net button using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an array of strings below:

```
string[] arr = new string[4] {"a" , "b" , "c" , "d"};
```

And i want to add each string one by one on a textbox after pressing asp.net button.

```
<asp:Button ID="btn_Showelements" runat="server" Text="Show Element" OnClick="btn_Showelements_Click" />
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="tb_ShowElement" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
```

So, what should i do. Kindly suggest me. Waiting for reply .Thanks

Comment: use a loop to iterate and assign it to textbox.

Comment: As a result, you want to see your textbox as `abcd`?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :

```
    string[] arr = new string[4] {"a" , "b" , "c" , "d"};
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
      str.Append(arr[i] + " ");
    }

    tb_ShowElement.Text = str.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this?

```
void btn_Showelements_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string[] arr = new string[4] { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
   string s = string.Join("", arr); //s will be abcd
   tb_ShowElement.Text = s;
}
```

Comment: @user3122821 Using Javascript? This question is asked for C#, not Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `foreach` loop block

```
string[] arr = new string[4] {"a" , "b" , "c" , "d"};
foreach(string str in arr)
{
   tb_ShowElement.Text += str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
By doing this.On each click next element on the **array** will appear.

```
        private static int i = 0;
        private static string str = string.Empty;
        protected void btn_Showelements_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] arr = new string[4] { "a", "b", "c", "d" };

            if (i < arr.Length)
            {
                str += arr[i];

                i++;
                tb_ShowElement.Text = str.ToString();
            }
        }
```